# Tensorflow hub: Extracting features from the topmost convolutional layer of a Resnet50

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, resnet, tensorflow-hub

I am using Tensorflow Hub to extract features from an image. Namely, I am using the module `hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3")`.

Because I want to extract features from the last convolutional layer, I am a bit confused which dictonary output should I use from the `Resnet50`. For example:

```
image = ...
embedding_module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3")
output = embedding_module(image, signature="image_feature_vector",
                          as_dict=True)
```

Now, if we print out the keys from this dictionary there are 3 different keys which I don't know the difference between.

- `resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2`
- `resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/conv3`
- `resnet_v2_50/block4`

What I find confusing is that all them have an output that has the same shape `(7, 7, 2048)`, yet the values of `resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2` and `resnet_v2_50/block4` are different from `resnet_v2_50/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v2/conv3`. Can someone point me to which key should be used for feature extraction from the last convolutional layer of the `Resnet50` as well as what is the difference between each of the keys I listed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

according [the official manual](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3) we can directly use `module(xxx)` to get result.

it works fine for me

```py
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3")
features = module(images)
```

Actually I'm also trying to figure out how to get the right last layer by `name` instead some pre-provided API which lacks flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow2, we can do as below.
For more docs: [link](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/5)

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

# as per updated docs
model = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/5")

imagePath = "......."
image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

embeddings = model(image)
```